# Plasma composition

Tags: experimental-physics, plasma-physics

Good day all,
I am looking for a way to estimate the composition of a thermal plasma formed by flowing gas between two charged electrodes.
I understand that when plasma is formed this way, it would be composed of a number of species.
Please is anyone able to point me in the right direction of finding an equation/correlation/data to allow me estimate the composition of the plasma for any gas?

Thank you

Comment: So like the [Saha equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Yes, but the gas I’m looking at is CH4 so I’m not sure I can use the Saha equation as it is for gases of single atomic species. Or am I missing something?  Thanks

Comment: I believe you can use Saha for C, C$^+$, H and $H^+$ separately (see [this LibreText article](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Astronomy__Cosmology/Stellar_Atmospheres_(Tatum)/08%3A_Boltzmann's_and_Saha's_Equations/8.06%3A_Saha's_Equation) that solves it for $\text{H}_2\text{O}$).